# How to create a local repo using apt-mirror without a server

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I know that this question has been repeated so many times before, but I'm at a loss of what to do with my mirrored repo.

I've mirror archive.ubuntu using apt-mirror and now I want to point apt to the local directory (not a server) and pull the packages from there.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, running a web server isn't a problem, even if you just want to serve the local system and not any network. There is lots of software in the Ubuntu archive that you can install to provide this service.

There's nothing special about server software; it's just software that allows a program to connect to it. For instance, the Transmission Bit Torrent client that's used in Ubuntu desktop by default, includes a built-in web server so you can connect to it via a browser. If you bind your web server to 127.0.0.1, then only clients on that computer can connect to the server.